# Calling KeGetCurrentThread() in DriverEntry() and inputing _KTHREAD Address in WinDbg gives (null) value for WaitPrcb member variable

Tags: windbg

OK so I have a kernel mode WDF device driver and in DriverEntry I've got two lines of code (see at the bottom). I then take the address displayed in DebugView by the DbgPrintEx statement then enter this command at the WinDbg command line as follows:

```
dt _KTHREAD 0xFFFFA80000050000
```

Gives the following output and at the bottom of this output shows **WaitPrcb** equal to (null):

```
lkd> dt _KTHREAD 00007ff69a380000
ntdll!_KTHREAD
+0x000 Header           : _DISPATCHER_HEADER
+0x018 SListFaultAddress : 0x00000000`00000040 Void
+0x020 QuantumTarget    : 0
+0x028 InitialStack     : (null) 
+0x030 StackLimit       : (null) 
+0x038 StackBase        : 0x00000180`00000000 Void
+0x040 ThreadLock       : 0xcd09b400`0eba1f0e
+0x048 CycleTime        : 0x685421cd`4c01b821
+0x050 CurrentRunTime   : 0x70207369
+0x054 ExpectedRunTime  : 0x72676f72
+0x058 KernelStack      : 0x6f6e6e61`63206d61 Void
+0x060 StateSaveArea    : 0x6e757220`65622074 _XSAVE_FORMAT
+0x068 SchedulingGroup  : 0x20534f44`206e6920 _KSCHEDULING_GROUP
+0x070 WaitRegister     : _KWAIT_STATUS_REGISTER
+0x071 Running          : 0x6f 'o'
+0x072 Alerted          : [2]  "de"
+0x074 SpareMiscFlag0   : 0y0
+0x074 ReadyTransition  : 0y1
+0x074 ProcessReadyQueue : 0y1
+0x074 WaitNext         : 0y1
+0x074 SystemAffinityActive : 0y0
+0x074 Alertable        : 0y1
+0x074 UserStackWalkActive : 0y0
+0x074 ApcInterruptRequest : 0y0
+0x074 QuantumEndMigrate : 0y1
+0x074 UmsDirectedSwitchEnable : 0y0
+0x074 TimerActive      : 0y1
+0x074 SystemThread     : 0y1
+0x074 ProcessDetachActive : 0y0
+0x074 CalloutActive    : 0y0
+0x074 ScbReadyQueue    : 0y0
+0x074 ApcQueueable     : 0y0
+0x074 ReservedStackInUse : 0y1
+0x074 UmsPerformingSyscall : 0y0
+0x074 ApcPendingReload : 0y1
+0x074 TimerSuspended   : 0y1
+0x074 SuspendedWaitMode : 0y0
+0x074 Reserved         : 0y00001010000 (0x50)
+0x074 MiscFlags        : 0n168627502
+0x078 AutoAlignment    : 0y0
+0x078 DisableBoost     : 0y0
+0x078 UserAffinitySet  : 0y1
[...]
+0x2c8 WaitPrcb         : (null)
```

The following two lines of code are taken from DriverEntry. **The question comes down to is what am I doing wrong and why is WaitPrcb (null) ?**

```
1. _KTHREAD* pKthread = KeGetCurrentThread();
2. DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_SYSTEM_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[ProcessSwitch...] pKTHREAD = %p\n", pKthread);
```

Comment: Are you sure that thread is still running when you inspect it in the debugger? The data dumped in your dt output is looking at an exe header. The text for "program cannot be run" is sitting in the values above.

Comment: @Josh thanks. I'm quite certain that the thread which I've obtained the _KTHREAD value is not running. Is this the reason why WaitPrcb member variable is shown as (null) ?

Comment: You are dumping the memory from a dangling pointer. In the instance here, it is looking at an exe header.

Comment: @josh thanks. Then are you saying that WaitPrcb member variable will only contain a valid address if the thread that this variables belongs to is in a running state ?

Comment: The WaitPrcb member will only contain meaningful data if the object you are dumping out is actually a KTHEAD object. Right now it isn't. Kernel objects stick around until all references haven been released. Once an object is deleted, the memory at that address can be reclaimed for something else.

Comment: @joshpoley how did you find out that this is an EXE header?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Most of the values looked like garbage, and anytime I see a bunch of hex values in the 0x41 through 0x7A range I immediately think "string". Reinterpreting the data as a string I saw the text "program cannot be run" which is a common PE header text string, especially at that offset (if you were to inspect the first two bytes of the `_DISPATCH_HEADER` you would probably find 'MZ')

Comment: @joshpoley just to let you know I've tested a bit further and discovered that the Running member (found at +0x071) of the _KTHREAD structure (see OP) is 0.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just to address the comment by thomas and clarify what Josh Poley commented

Seeing a bunch of characters in ASCII printable range is a strong indicator that some thing is not Right

see below what is sitting in the dumped data

it is a QWORD and characters should be arranged considering Endianess but it is still a visible String

```
+0x048 CycleTime        : 0x685421cd`4c01b821
+0x050 CurrentRunTime   : 0x70207369
+0x054 ExpectedRunTime  : 0x72676f72
+0x058 KernelStack      : 0x6f6e6e61`63206d61 Void
+0x060 StateSaveArea    : 0x6e757220`65622074 _XSAVE_FORMAT
+0x068 SchedulingGroup  : 0x20534f44`206e6920 _KSCHEDULING_GROUP
```

[image]